# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError using JOOQ

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, jooq

I was trying to use JOOQ in glassfish. I used code generator like this:

```
java -cp jOOQ-lib/jooq-3.3.1.jar:jOOQ-lib/jooq-meta-3.3.1.jar:jOOQ-lib/jooq-codegen-3.3.1.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /db.xml
```

Then imported the generated folder to my project.(I'm not using jooq maven plugin). When I deploy web app in glassfish I see this in server.log

```
[#|2014-04-06T14:53:37.720+0430|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler|_ThreadID=670;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|org.jooq.impl.TableImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jooq/Schema;Lorg/jooq/Table;[Lorg/jooq/Field;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jooq.impl.TableImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jooq/Schema;Lorg/jooq/Table;[Lorg/jooq/Field;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

I have not changed any maven config just netbeans default config. maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

my db.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
  <jdbc>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/bulkdb?useUnicode=true</url>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pass</password>
  </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <inputSchema>bulkdb</inputSchema>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
        </database>
        <target>
            <packageName>bulkdb</packageName>
            <directory>/home/user/jooq</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>

</configuration>
```

What is going wrong? Can someone help?

**[UPDATE]**

Actually there is two version of JOOQ in app server class path: one in lib directory of the domain(domain1/lib/) with version 3.1 and second one is 3.3.1 that is bundled in war file. Does this cause problems?

Comment: Although I'm not too familiar with netbeans, but could you check if the `jooq.jar` is within your dependencies folder?

Comment: @tmarwen yes, jooq-3.3.1.jar is in dependency folder

Comment: And you're *sure* that you have jOOQ 3.3.1 bundled in your app server, and not an old version of jOOQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually there is two version of JOOQ in app server class path: one in lib directory of the domain(domain1/lib/) with version 3.1 and second one is 3.3.1 that is bundled in war file. Does this cause problems?

Yes, of course :-)

If you want to use both versions in parallel (do you really?), then you will probably need to resort to something like [OSGi](http://www.osgi.org) to be able to load the same class names in separate class loaders.

In your case, jOOQ 3.1 is loaded first by your application server, and thus jOOQ 3.3 cannot be loaded fully any more. The code generated with jOOQ 3.3 operates on new internal methods in `TableImpl`, which have been added in jOOQ 3.2 or 3.3, but since you're loading jOOQ 3.1, those methods aren't there. Note that this can happen with any external dependencies.

The solution here is really to remove jOOQ 3.1 from your application server.

Comment: Does 3.3.1 can run 3.1 generated code? Because I don't have access to other deployed applications. I can only replace jars in lib folder.

Comment: @MajidAzimi: Usually: No. Generated code might need to be re-generated when upgrading the runtime version. The internal APIs are often incompatible. You should always use the same jOOQ version for code-generation and runtime.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza: This is quite likely not strictly related to this question, which isn't using spring boot. Would you mind creating a new question?